# Javac error : "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, linux, jar, javac

I'm trying to compile java files on an EC2 instance, and am having trouble. I have several JAR files as well that are included in the classpath. The example would be a StockTrade.java (which is a stock trade object), which compiles completely without issue. In the same directory, there is the StockTradeGenerator.java, which will create StockTrade objects. When I try to compile this, it tells me it cannot find the StockTrade class (despite it being in the same directory already compiled. My syntax is:

```
javac -cp lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar src/StockTradeGenerator.java
```

Does anyone know what is making it so I cannot compile the Generator file?

Comment: Try this below, which addes the current directory and the src directory to the classpath 
javac -cp lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar:.:src src/StockTradeGenerator.java

Comment: Related issue that keeps showing up: I have a class within the StockTrade.java called TradeType that is an enum of either BUY or SELL. When I try to compile, it says it cannot find symbol "TradeType". How would I include that when I compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also include current directory or the directory where your StockTrade class is present.